# Algorithms for image generation using input vector (audio visualisation)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am looking for algorithms, and/or libraries (C/C++) that given a vector of floats compute an image. The use case is the visualisation of audio (music) on a light matrix. As this is going to be used for audio visualisation, it is a good property for the algorithms that small changes in the input vector cause small changes in the output image; in other words, similar vectors produce similar images.

The input vector consists of the frequencies determined by a Fourier transform on some audio. The image matrix dimensions range from about 50 by 50.

Background: I am placing a bunch of lightbulbs around a waggon forming a matrix. Inside the waggon is a stereo system playing music. I am going to connect a Raspberry Pi which will slice the audio stream into windows, perform a Fourier transform on it and based on the frequencies determined determine some configuration (colours, intensities, shapes, animations) for the lights.

Some papers on this matter would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there will be specific audio visualization papers, but you may find lots of resources about signal visualization. Looks like this is limited only by your creativity, so it is hard to give an actual solution. I don't think the frequencies of the audio are useful the way you are computing, probably the output vector of the FT will be more useful, since you have both the frequencies and their intensities. This is more data to play in two dimensions.

Comment: You can get ideas of algorithms from glslsandbox.com and shadertoy.com